# Disable hyperlink highlighting for specific identifier in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I wrote the following in a JavaScript file:

```
grunt.task.run('shell:jspm');
```

Visual Studio thinks I want the phrase `shell:jspm` to be highlighted as if it were a hyperlink, but it is not.

I'd like to disable this match. Is that possible?